# Testing the return value : command not found

Tags: linux, bash, function, boolean, return-value

I have written a function to convert yes or no answers to true or false (0 or 1). However I get 'command not found' error every time I run my script. Please help me troubleshoot it

```
get_boolean(){
    #==============================================================================================
    # Returns false if the first argument is NO and returns true if it is YES.
    # If the first argument is not a valid YES or NO,
    # then the return value depends on the default specified by argument 2 (Default value)
    #==============================================================================================

    if [ "$1" == 'NO' ] || [ "$1" == 'no' ] || [ "$1" == 'No' ] || [ "$1" == 'N' ] || [ "$1" == 'n' ]; then
            return 1;
    elif [ "$1" == 'YES' ] || [ "$1" == 'yes' ] || [ "$1" == 'Yes' ] || [ "$1" == 'Y' ] || [ "$1" == 'y' ]; then
            return 0;
    elif [ "$2" == 'NO' ] || [ "$2" == 'no' ] || [ "$2" == 'No' ] || [ "$2" == 'N' ] || [ "$2" == 'n' ]; then
            return 1;
    elif [ "$2" == 'YES' ] || [ "$2" == 'yes' ] || [ "$2" == 'Yes' ] || [ "$2" == 'Y' ] || [ "$2" == 'y' ]; then
            return 0;
    fi
}

read -p 'Do you want to drop the table of invalids? [n]:' DROP_TABLE_OF_INVALIDS
echo "After read: $DROP_TABLE_OF_INVALIDS"
DROP_TABLE_OF_INVALIDS=get_boolean "$DROP_TABLE_OF_INVALIDS" 'n'
echo "After assignment: $DROP_TABLE_OF_INVALIDS"
if $DROP_TABLE_OF_INVALIDS; then
        echo "Hello. I will drop the table"
fi
```

When I run the script, I get these errors :

```
bash-3.2$ sh test.sh
Do you want to drop the table of invalids? [n]:y
After read: y
test.sh: line 24: y: command not found
After assignment: y
test.sh: line 26: y: command not found
bash-3.2$ sh test.sh
Do you want to drop the table of invalids? [n]:n
After read: n
test.sh: line 24: n: command not found
After assignment: n
test.sh: line 26: n: command not found
```

Update: The code below worked (Thanks Barmar!)

```
get_boolean(){
        #==============================================================================================
        # Outputs false if the first argument is NO and outputs true if it is YES.
        # If the first argument is not a valid YES or NO,
        # then the output value depends on the default specified by argument 2 (Default value)
        #==============================================================================================

        if [ "$1" == 'NO' ] || [ "$1" == 'no' ] || [ "$1" == 'No' ] || [ "$1" == 'N' ] || [ "$1" == 'n' ]; then
                        echo false;
        elif [ "$1" == 'YES' ] || [ "$1" == 'yes' ] || [ "$1" == 'Yes' ] || [ "$1" == 'Y' ] || [ "$1" == 'y' ]; then
                        echo true;
        elif [ "$2" == 'NO' ] || [ "$2" == 'no' ] || [ "$2" == 'No' ] || [ "$2" == 'N' ] || [ "$2" == 'n' ]; then
                        echo false;
        elif [ "$2" == 'YES' ] || [ "$2" == 'yes' ] || [ "$2" == 'Yes' ] || [ "$2" == 'Y' ] || [ "$2" == 'y' ]; then
                        echo true;
        fi
}

read -p 'Do you want to drop the table of invalids? [n]:' DROP_TABLE_OF_INVALIDS
echo "After read: $DROP_TABLE_OF_INVALIDS"
DROP_TABLE_OF_INVALIDS=$(get_boolean "$DROP_TABLE_OF_INVALIDS" 'n')
echo "After assignment: $DROP_TABLE_OF_INVALIDS"
if $DROP_TABLE_OF_INVALIDS; then
                echo "Hello. I will drop the table"
fi
```

Here are the edits that made it work:

- The function 'echo'es instead of returning.
- The output values are bash true or false (useful for testing in if, otherwise getting 0: command not found or 1: command not found)
- The function call is enclosed in '$(' and ')'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax:

```
DROP_TABLE_OF_INVALIDS=get_boolean "$DROP_TABLE_OF_INVALIDS" 'n'
```

means to set the environment variable `DROP_TABLE_OF_INVALIDS` to the string `"get_boolean"` while executing the command `"$DROP_TABLE_OF_INVALIDS" 'n'".

The way to assign a variable with the output of a function is:

```
DROP_TABLE_OF_INVALIDS=$(get_boolean "$DROP_TABLE_OF_INVALIDS" 'n')
```

Also, you need to change the function to use `echo` instead of `return`. `return` sets the exit status, not the output of the function.

Comment: Thank you! So kind of you to make it clear that return just sets the exit status and it is not the function output unlike C, C++, Java. Anyway, I will post the edits made that corrected the code.

Comment: I'm not sure your `if $DROP_TABLE_OF_INVALIDS` will work when the function returns `""`. `if` needs an argument.

Comment: Yes.. I should remove it.. I already have a default value being passed to the function.. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems. The line

```
DROP_TABLE_OF_INVALIDS=get_boolean "$DROP_TABLE_OF_INVALIDS" 'n'
```

doesn't call `get_boolean`. It tries running the command named by `DROP_TABLE_OF_INVALIDS` with a modified environment. You would want:

```
DROP_TABLE_OF_INVALIDS=$(get_boolean "$DROP_TABLE_OF_INVALIDS" 'n')
```

This leads to the second problem, which is that `DROP_TABLE_OF_INVALIDS` contains the standard output of `get_boolean`, but you are using a return value. Try calling it like this:

```
if get_boolean "$DROP_TABLE_OF_INVALIDS" 'n'; then
    ...
fi
```

where the return value is tested directory, instead of capturing a string to test.

The third problem is that you try to return an empty string. The `return` statement can only return a numerical value; it's not like a function in other languages where it returns an arbitrary value. If the first argument is empty, you need to decide if that's true or false; false seems like a good default, so return 0. Or, you could ignore it treat it as a case to use the value of `$2`.

---

A simpler version would be

```
get_boolean(){
    #==================================================================================
    # Returns false if the first argument is NO and returns true if it is YES.
    # If the first argument is not a valid YES or NO,
    # then the return value depends on the default specified by argument 2 (Default value)
    #==================================================================================
    case $1 in
        NO|No|no|N|n|"" ) return 1 ;;
        YES|yes|Yes|Y|y) return 0;;
        * ) case $2 in
            YES|yes|Yes|Y|y) return 0;;
            * ) return 1 ;;
            esac ;;
    esac
}
```